# Java 8 Stream API: NPE при создании Map при значениях null

Tags: java, java-stream

Одним моим коллегой был обнаружен баг в `Stream API`: если создавать Map из stream() при помощи `.collect(Collectors.toMap())`, то всё валится с `NPE` при значениях `null` (не ключах).

```
header.set(Stream.of(Utils.<String, Object>entry("description", status.getDescription())).
                        collect(utils.entriesToMap()));
```

Если `status.getDescription() == null`, то NPE.

Как думаете, знатоки, чем можно объяснить этот феномен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При заполнении результирующей мапы в реализации коллектора по умолчанию используется метод `merge` (JDK 1.8b112 `java.util.stream.Collectors:1319`):

```
BiConsumer<M, T> accumulator
        = (map, element) -> map.merge(keyMapper.apply(element),
                                      valueMapper.apply(element), mergeFunction);
```

А если заглянуть в реализацию этого метода в классе `HashMap`, то можно увидеть следующее (`java.util.HashMap:1223`):

```
if (value == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();
```

Если не указывать явно, то при использовании `Collectors.toMap()`, всё собирается в экземпляр класса `HashMap`.

Варианты решения:

- указывать явно, какую мапу использовать, если в ней нет подобной проверки (`HashMap` и `TreeMap` к таким не относятся, как и все, которые наследуются от интерфейса `Map`, не переопределяя метод `merge`, потому что в дефолтной реализации тоже есть строка `Objects.requireNonNull(value)`)
- самим написать метод добавления новых элементов в мапу и не использовать `merge`:

  ```
  .collect(
      HashMap::new,
      (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()),
      HashMap::putAll
  );
  ```
- использовать `forEach` с сайд-эффектом (не надо так, используйте лучше второй вариант):

  ```
  Map<K, V> newMap = ...
  stream.forEach(e -> newMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
  ```